# Linebreak at itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, line-breaking, itemize

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[about] Foo\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit

\item[about] sort rules(...)
\begin{sloppypar}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit\end{sloppypar}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

and it looks as follows

[image: mwe]

As you can see, I want a line break after the `\item[customize]`. Both work fine, but at the second one, there is a small extra space between the "customize" and the text... That looks very well, I think.

But there must be another way to do this, instead of using `\begin{sloppypar}` all the time, or?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sloppypar` initiates a paragraph, which you can also achieve by leaving a blank line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

  \item[about] Foo\\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit

  \item[about] sort rules(...)
    \begin{sloppypar}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit
    \end{sloppypar}

  \item[about] sort rules(...)

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```